# Same declaration with and without const, why?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have

```
T& operator[](int i) const;
const T& operator[](int i) const;
```

how can I use one instead of another one? Why would one define these?

Comment: Does that even compile?!

Comment: Return types do not participate in function overloading.
So you cannot use them as overloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can - they are ambiguous. Typically you'd want this:

```
T& operator[](int i); // note no trailing const
const T& operator[](int i) const;
```

The first overload is selected when your object is non-`const` - it's a better match than the second, and the second is selected when the instance is `const` - the first doesn't match at all.

Answer (score 1):

The correct pair is this (I think your post has typo, as you seem to mean the following):

```
T& operator[](int i); //without const;
const T& operator[](int i) const;
```

As for your question, I would suggest you to define both of them, because you may end up using both in your code. Here is one example.

```
void f(X const &a, X & b)
{
      int i = get_index();
      std::cout << a[i] << std::endl; //this invokes const version
      std::cout << b[i] << std::endl; //this invokes non-const version
}
```

In this code, `a[i]` invokes const-version of `operator[]`, because `a` is a const object, which means it cannot invoke non-const version. However, in case of `b[i]`, the C++ rules dictate that it should invoke non-const version, because the object `b` is non-const and there exists a non-const overload of `operator[]`, so that is preffered. In the absence of non-const overload, even `b[i]` would invoke const version which is not desirable on many occasions, such as when you would like to write data at index `i`, as:

```
b[i] = item; //it must invoke non-const version in order 
             //to compile and work (properly).
```

Hope that helps.